# Apply an `unsafe` keyword to a lambda expression in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, callback, keyword, unsafe

Why is it impossible to apply an `unsafe` keyword to a lambda expression in C#?

Here is what I tried:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Action<int> a = unsafe i => Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nBI0dX.

Here is the error I got:

> Invalid expression term 'unsafe'

I need this solely for studying purposes. I am learning the .NET and see no reasons to prohibit the unsafe keyword before a lambda expression. So, I am interested why it might have been prohibited.

Comment: this can help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/4447796/8207463

Comment: @BerBar, could you, please, be more specific in which way should the answer you posted help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions#local-function-syntax) instead, which has [some advantages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions#local-functions-vs-lambda-expressions) over lambda expression and supports `unsafe` keyword:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        unsafe void a(int i) => Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```